# Successive Pattern matching using Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a scenario in which I need to perform successive operations on a particular string. 
For example consider the test string "{string{one}}".

First,I need to match the pattern within the inner braces from the given string; in this string it is {one} . Then match the pattern in the outer braces along with the quotes i.e "{string}".

I have written the RegEx to match  the string within the inner and the outer braces, but the RegEx doesn't match the quotes.The RegEx is

```
        Regex : ({\w+})(?!\b{.*(}+)(?=}+"))
```

Please provide suggestion to match the string along with the quotes for this expression.
Thanks.

Comment: what would be the output if input is `{foo{bar{buz}{bal}}bam}` ?

Comment: @Avinash..two matches found- {buz} and {ball}

Comment: Are you just looking for `String regex = "\\{[^{}]+\\}"`?

Comment: Please clarify what you need in the question. Right now, I assume you need `foobam` to be extracted from `{foo{bar{buz}{bal}}bam}`.

Comment: Yes,I need foobam along with {} and "" i.e "{foobam}"

Comment: Please check [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/kwJlC2). Not sure you need that kind of a solution though.

Comment: I would try that in a less complicated manner. If you could use the very basic `replace` function or so, something like this could be enough: `("{.*?)({\w+})(.*?}")` and replace with `$2` for `{one}` and with `$1$3` for `"{string}"`.